# can't iterate over a file correctly

Tags: c++

```
 std::fstream pasaka("my_file", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    std::fstream pusuku("my_file1", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    std::string line;


    if (pasaka.is_open()) 
    {

        //while (std::getline(pasaka, line))
            //std::cout << line << std::endl;
           // pusuku << line << std::endl;

        while (!pasaka.eof())
        {
            if (pasaka.get() == 'a')
            {
                pasaka.seekp((pasaka.tellp() - static_cast<std::streampos>(1)));
                pasaka.put('u');
                pasaka.seekp(pasaka.tellp());
            }
            else if (pasaka.get() == 'A')
            {
                pasaka.seekp((pasaka.tellp() - static_cast<std::streampos>(1)));
                pasaka.put('U');
                pasaka.seekp(pasaka.tellp());
            }
        }
        pusuku.close();
        pasaka.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Faild to open" << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
```

the issues:

1. if the code that is commented (first while loop and everything in it ) the program does 0 switches

2)if A is found it doesn't delete the A characther but just adds U

result received: ( from txt file )
uuuuuuu
UAUAAAA

result expected ( from txt file )
uuuuuuu
UUUUUUU

Comment: Not checking well, `while (!pasaka.eof())` looks [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: I suggest you open the file in binary mode, not text mode.

Comment: What do you expect `pasaka.seekp(pasaka.tellp());` to accomplish?